# create parition for xen with lvm on raid-1

Tags: ubuntu, xen, lvm, partition, raid1

First I don't have any experience creating xen, lvm and RAID-1 server, thus after several reading I stumbled upon this  [ubuntu documentation to install xen](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Xen). 
BUT, because in the documentation it doesn't specify how to use it with raid, I created the a partition like so:

```
md0 (/dev/md0)
+------------------------------------------------------------+
|                   LVM                                      |
+------------------------------------------------------------+

hdd1 (/dev/sda)
+----------------------------------------++------------------+
   raid                                  ||    swap          |  
+----------------------------------------++------------------+

hdd2 (/dev/sdb)
+----------------------------------------++------------------+
   raid                                  ||    swap          |  
+----------------------------------------++------------------+
```

inside lvm (/dev/md0), I created logical partition like so :

```
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| / (root)  |              reserved  LVM for XEN             |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

the question **is this the correct way to create partition for lvm used for xen ? if this is wrong please show me the correct way to do it**

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "one size fits all" approach to file system and RAID volume layout.  It will vary based on need and experience.  What you have should work.

That being said...

Why don't you have swap mirrored?  If dom0 (the hypervisor domain manager) swaps at all, or even if it doesn't, and one of your disks die you run the risk of the system crashing when that swap space unexpectedly disappears or causes problems otherwise.

Comment: i am still new about this, so if i create logical partition for swap, will that solve it?

Comment: That would work.  Just keep in mind, dom0 shouldn't need that much swap so you don't need to create a big volume for it.